# Update/Create /page/menu or /page/menu

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Cannot find the API/endpoint to upload a pdf version of a restaurant menu so /page/tabs/menu can display it.

From my googling I cannot find the endpoint to even upload the PDF.

Facebook links:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs#add
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/tabs/#Creating - There is a clear message that the page need to have more than 2000 like. But from the FB UI you can add a menu on any page

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/ - Only support images

Comment: what makes you believe that you could upload a pdf?

Comment: The documentation you are looking for is for custom, 3rd-party page tab _apps_ - that has nothing to do with other default “tab” functionality Facebook provides. // Which page fields you can update via API, is listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/#Updating

Comment: One would think that if the main GUI of the Facebook app has a function the API should also have the function. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/#Updating - Does not have the fields I need to update. I was hoping there was a endpoint that I have not discovered in the Facebook Developer section that allowed for this.